# Group by and add new column with min value between dates - pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this Pandas dataframe:

[image]

I want a new DF to group them by ['ticked_id','time_a'] and add a new column with the min difference in time (hh), SQL code that works:

```
SELECT ticket_id, DATEDIFF('hh', time_a, MIN(time_b)) each_diff from ...
```

I've tried to group them but it results on an object that I can't see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group the data and get a column with the minimum date of the `time_b` column you can do:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['ticket_id', 'time_a'])['time_b'].min().reset_index()
```

I don't know the datatypes of your `time_a` and `time_b` columns but if they are timestamps you can then do the following to get the difference in hours:

```
df_grouped['each_diff'] = (df_grouped['time_b'] - df_grouped['time_a').astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ticket_id': [1, 2, 2],
    'time_a': ['2021-07-21 12:00:01', '2021-07-21 12:00:01', '2021-07-21 12:00:01'],
    'time_b': ['2021-07-21 14:00:02', '2021-07-21 13:00:05', '2021-07-21 17:00:10']
})
df.time_a = pd.to_datetime(df.time_a)
df.time_b = pd.to_datetime(df.time_b)
```

```
   ticket_id              time_a              time_b
0          1 2021-07-21 12:00:01 2021-07-21 14:00:02
1          2 2021-07-21 12:00:01 2021-07-21 13:00:05
2          2 2021-07-21 12:00:01 2021-07-21 17:00:10
```

this

```
df = df.groupby(['ticket_id', 'time_a'], as_index=False).agg(time_b_min=('time_b', 'min'))
df['diff'] = df.time_b_min - df.time_a
```

gives you

```
   ticket_id              time_a          time_b_min            diff
0          1 2021-07-21 12:00:01 2021-07-21 14:00:02 0 days 02:00:01
1          2 2021-07-21 12:00:01 2021-07-21 13:00:05 0 days 01:00:04
```

Comment: Works! like this solution :). Didn't know that you can to .add on a groupy, Thanks!!!